# DisplayName não funciona em relacionamento

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc

tenho uma **model**:

```
public class TalaoCode : ITalaoCode
    {
        [Key]
        public int TalaoCodeId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Equipe")]
        public int EquipeId { get; set; }

        [DisplayName("Equipe")]
        public virtual Equipe Equipe { get; set; }
}
```

Veja que coloquei o atributo `DisplayName` em ambos, porém quando é chamado na view criado pelo `Scanfolding` padrão, ele não existe o texto do `DisplayName` e sim `EquipeId`

View criada pelo Scanfolding

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipeId, "EquipeId", new { @class = "control-label col-md-2" })
```

Já tentei utilizar `[Display(Name ="Equipe")]` porém também sem sucesso. Sempre aparece EquipeId

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

O que acontece é que você está especificando o parâmetro `labelText`, então o que está no `DisplayName` não será mostrado.

Altere seu `LabelFor` para

```
@Html.LabelFor(model => model.EquipeId, htmlAttributes: new { @class = "control-label" })
```

Comment: verdade, não tinha reparado, scanfolding piolho..rs